# How to retry lost connections for reliable transmissions?

Tags: java, sockets

I am sending xml data to server via socket programming. I have found that sometimes when the server is down and the client reports socket timeout, I am unable to send or receive.

I want to handle this exception and try to resend for 3 to 4 times. Should I use Thread.sleep, write in loop, or is there any better approach?

```
   private String sendRequestToChannel(String request) {

    String xmlData = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    String line = null;
    String lineSep = null;
    String data = null;
    StringBuffer serverData = null;


    try {

        Socket cliSocket = new Socket();

        cliSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cliSocket.getOutputStream()));

        bw.write("POST " + PATH + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        bw.write("Host: " + HOST + "\r\n");
        bw.write("Content-Length: " + request.length() + "\r\n");
        bw.write("Pragma: cache\r\n");
        bw.write("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate\r\n");
        bw.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        bw.write("\r\n");
        bw.write(request);
        bw.flush();

        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cliSocket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println("Step 4 : Getting Input Stream");
        serverData = new StringBuffer("");


        lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            serverData.append(line);
            serverData.append(lineSep);
        }

        data = serverData.toString();
        int index = data.indexOf("<");

        if (index != -1) {
            xmlData = data.substring(index);

        } else {
            System.out.println("\r\n \r\n  XML Data Not Retrived");
        }


    } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException uh) {
        uh.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$  in sendRequestToChannel : UnknownHostException " + uh.getMessage());
        return "   in sendRequestToChannel : UnknownHostException " + uh.toString();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$  in sendRequestToChannel :  IOException " + ioe.getMessage());
        return " in sendRequestToChannel :   IOException " + ioe.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$  in sendRequestToChannel :  Exception " + e.getMessage());
        return " in sendRequestToChannel :  Exception " + e.toString();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null) {
                bw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SA_Caesar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            if (rd != null) {
                rd.close();

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SA_Caesar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);



        }

        bw = null;
        rd = null;
        line = null;
        lineSep = null;
        data = null;
        serverData = null;

    }
    return xmlData;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem an application faces when its remote service goes down is that there's **no way at all** to predict when it will return, if ever.

You are already using a TCP connection which will retry when faced with short-term unreachable services, but by the time TCP has declared the connection dead, you actually don't increase reliability by automatically trying to re-establish the connection. For example, if it takes two days for the remote server to come back, will your application be able to act as if it had never been down? Will all necessary data be queued during the outage? Will the semantics of a connected system be preserved across a weekend's failure? How about if the remote service is down for 5 days?

The best that you can do from a system perspective is notify the operator that there is a fault which requires attention. This is why we still have operators and will for the foreseeable future.